# calculate Shasum for multiple files in Mac automator

Tags: macos, terminal, checksum, automator

I'm trying to run shasum on mulitple files and copy the output to the clipboard.

In the terminal it's simple calculate the checksum on multiple files.

shasum  /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0708.MP4 /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0710.MP4 /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0711.MP4 /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0712.MP4 /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0713.MP4 /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0714.MP4 /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/100CANON/A99A0715.MP4

and the ouput is the checksum /path for each file on a seperate line

in automator
run shell script
shasum /Volumes/EOS_DIGITAL/DCIM/card2/A99A0686.MP4 outputs the checksum and path
then copy to clipboard does it's thing.

when I try dragging multiple files in the automator work flow i get
"Run Shell Script" encountered an error :zsh:2: exec format error:/path
zsh:3: exec format error:/path zsh:4: exec format error:/path .... repeating for how many files I try dragging in to the work flow.

When the workflow is saved as an application it outputs a single checksum that doesn't match any one file.

Is there a way to get the application to output the checksum for each file and copy all the results to the clipboard so I can paste them into a spread sheet as a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Run Shell Script` action, set the 'Pass input:' pulldown menu to 'as arguments', then use the following code:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    shasum "$f"
done
```

Comment: is there any reason that this would work in Mojave but not consistently in Catalina. In Catalina when I drop a selection of 10 files it only gives the checksum for the second file, but if I select only files 3-10 it works fine.

Comment: @dano: I'm on Big Sur so I can't test Mojave or Catalina. On my system it works on every trial (I've tried 1 file, 3, 7, 10, 11, an entire folder of 28, and 54 files over two folders). My guess would be that shasum is throwing an error on the third file, but that's just a guess. Try a different file set to confirm or refute that.

Comment: weirdly it works fine as a folder action or quick action and as an app it works with a bunch of different file sets.  It seems there is something about that particular file set that is a problem.
thanks for your help.